# Spring AMQP take action on message timeout

Tags: java, spring-amqp, message-listener

I am using Spring AMQP with asynchronous messaging. My model assumes that there are two applications A and B, both producers and consumers.

- A sends job request to B and starts listening.
- B are listening for job request, and when it comes, starts job and periodically sends progress messages to A.
- B sends job finish message to A after job is finished.
- A consumes progress messages until job finish message comes, then A exists.

I am using `@RabbitListener` on class level and `@RabbitHandler` on method level, for message consuming. Everything works nice and design is clean, I like Spring's solution.

My problem is - I have no idea how to detect, and how to act, when A is expecting to receive progress message from B (any message) and it's not coming in. Is there any timeout for such cases? If so, how to implement callback method?

I found some timeout settings, but they usually works for connection itself, or only when using RPC pattern (one request one response).

Desired solution is - A should receive progress message every minute. If no progress message is consumed for, say, 3 minutes, I want to cancel the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using async consumers, there's no mechanism to generate an event if a message is not received within some time period.

You can schedule your own task though and cancel/reschedule the task when a message arrives.

Use a `TaskScheduler` with

`future = schedule(myRunnable, new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 180000));`

use `future.cancel()` when a message arrives.

Comment: Too bad, because current solution is pretty clean... Is there any chance that such feature could be requested and implemented in future? After all, native rabbitmq client allows to receive with timeout. For Spring it could be just a matter of introducing an event for it.

Comment: It would actually be rather trivial to implement (and this is not the first time it's been asked for); plus it would avoid any race conditions because the "no message" event could be published on the same listener thread. Feel free to open a new feature [JIRA issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/AMQP). In the meantime, instead of using a `@RabbitListener` for the progress messages, you could use `rabbitTemplate.receiveAndConvert()` with the [template configured with a receive timeout](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp//reference/html/_introduction.html#_blocking_receive_methods).

Comment: Available in [1.6.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/1.6.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/_reference.html#_event_consumption). We expect to release the first milestone of 1.6 in a few weeks with the GA expected later in the year. Please give it a spin if you get a chance to make sure it satisfies your needs.

Comment: Yeah, I saw the progress. Thank you very much.